# How do you import discord.py on ubuntu terminal?

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, discord, discord.py

So I've been using windows 10 for quite a while but my windows has many problems so I am now using ubuntu.

```
pip install discord
```

used to always work;
but I just can't find any tutorial about installing discord.py on ubuntu.

The following all don't work:
`Pip install discord`
And
`Pip install discord.py`

Comment: `pip3 install discord`  depending on what version of Ubuntu you are using I suggest making an alias entry in your .bashrc file `alias pip=pip3`

Comment: Remember Unix/Linux is case sensitive. Pip and pip are not the same command. As @Alexander indicates the command would usually be 'pip' or 'pip3' in lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe pip isn't added to your path. Try `python3 -m pip install discord`.